# AsyncTask, AsynTaskLoader or Executer with ViewModel, LiveData and Room?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

First I don't know everything in Android and Java I am working on that, in case you find lack of knowledge in my question.

When I read about the benefits of [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders?utm_campaign=adp_series_loaders_020216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog), I read that loaders run on separate threads to prevent unresponsive UI.

After appearing and reading of [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java) and **Room** and after reading [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lifecycle-aware-data-loading-with-android-architecture-components-f95484159de4), especially in the section 
**Observing data** which says

> In the `Loader` world, getting your data to your UI would involve a 
>   `LoaderManager`, calling `initLoader()` in the right place, and building a > ?`LoaderCallbacks`. The world is a bit more straightforward in the 
>   Architecture Components world. etc..

and the next section

**Load all the things** which says in the second paragraph

> For example, Room lets you have observarable queries — database queries 
>   that return `LiveData` so that database changes automatically propagate up 
>   through your `ViewModel` to your UI. Kind of like a `CursorLoader` without 
>   touching Cursors or Loaders.

All of the above implies that **ViewModel** and **LiveData** with **Room** can work in the **background thread**, I mean when we use **ViewModel** and **LiveData** with **Room** instead of **Loaders**, we needn't have used **AsyncTask** or **AsyncTaskLoader** or **Executer**

But in theses examples:

[android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample) which can be used as a template as they say in README.md,

In the **MainActivity.java** they write `mWordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this, .... ;` and if we trace `getAllWords()` deeply we find that the function is query of **select**, but when they want to **insert** data in **WordRepository.java**
 or **WordRoomDatabase.java** they use **AsyncTask**,

I mean why have they used **ViewModel** and **LiveData** and **Dao** with query of **select**, and in the query of **insert** they have **included** **AsyncTask** with **ViewModel** and **Dao**?, because as what implies above **ViewModel** and **LiveData** with **Room** can work in the **background thread**?

My previous question goes for this example [android-persistence
at step3_solution](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-persistence/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/codelab/step3_solution), I mean to **get** the data only **ViewModel** is used but to **insert** data like in [**DatabaseInitializer.java**](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-persistence/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/codelab/db/utils/DatabaseInitializer.java), **AsyncTask** is **included?**

Also in this example of [BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java), **Executer** is **included** when data has to be **inserted**?

Thank you very much

Comment: Use Kotlin with Coroutines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the MainActivity.java they write mWordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this, .... ; and if we trace getAllWords() deeply we find that the function is query of select,

Indeed, the `getAllWords()` is exposed from Room DAO as `LiveData<List<T>>`, therefore it can be observed, and internally Room will handle the asynchronous fetch task (executed on `ArchTaskExecutor.io()` which is a [two-threaded executor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/tags/android-p-preview-1/app-toolkit/runtime/src/main/java/android/arch/core/executor/DefaultTaskExecutor.java#33)).

> ```
> @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
> LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();
> ```

However, if you have an `insert`, then on Room DAO that is synchronous method, so they don't handle threading for you.

---

AsyncTask is one particular way to have your code executed on Android's default executor (read: a background thread) for background tasks:

> ```
> public static final Executor SERIAL_EXECUTOR = new SerialExecutor();
> private static volatile Executor sDefaultExecutor = SERIAL_EXECUTOR;
> ```

Which runs every task sequentially.

---

---

So the answer to your question is that because queries and inserts work differently.

Queries exposed as LiveData are tracking invalidation of the underlying database and re-query the result set for you if you did a write that would have changed this table. This way you don't need to manually query the database when you do a write that changes elements in a particular table. It is very convenient, actually.

Inserts are just, inserts. So they don't do magic for you in that case.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is a viable solution?

Comment: It's deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58767934/2413303

Comment: Why is `AsyncTask` mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because AsyncTask was deprecated about 6 months after this answer was written, probably

Answer (score -1):

> All of the above implies that ViewModel and LiveData with Room can work in the background thread, I mean when we use ViewModel and LiveData with Room instead of Loaders, we needn't have used AsyncTask or AsyncTaskLoader or Executer

They don't. They run on the current thread they were executed.  That is exactly why in the example you cited they still used an AsyncTask to move the work to a background thread.

Notice also that MutableLiveData have two methods to set its values.

```
public void postValue(T value) {
    super.postValue(value);
}

public void setValue(T value) {
    super.setValue(value);
}
```

`postValue(value)` is used to set the value of a `MutableLiveData` when in a background thread. Calling the `setValue(value)` while in the background will throw an exception if I remember it right.

Also, Loaders are deprecated as of API 28. You can read it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders?authuser=2).

> Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and LiveData. ViewModels survive configuration changes like Loaders but with less boilerplate. LiveData provides a lifecycle-aware way of loading data that you can reuse in multiple ViewModels. You can also combine LiveData using MediatorLiveData , and any observable queries, such as those from a Room database, can be used to observe changes to the data. ViewModels and LiveData are also available in situations where you do not have access to the LoaderManager, such as in a Service. Using the two in tandem provides an easy way to access the data your app needs without having to deal with the UI lifecycle. To learn more about LiveData see the LiveData guide and to learn more about ViewModels see the ViewModel guide.

Comment: We should use AsyncTask?

Comment: If you want to do work outside of the main thread to avoid blocking the main thread, there are alot more options available to you other than `AsyncTask`.  In other words avoid `AsyncTask` at all cost.