# ArrayList in Android AsynTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

How can I Create a class AsynkTask in which the class  DataContainer is filled. Continue to fill the  class DataContainer with synthetic data. After each new one Record should pause the AsynkTask class for a short time (200ms).?

```
public class DataContainer  {
    public ArrayList<String> mGlobalDataStore1 = initializeData();

    static ArrayList<String> initializeData(){
        ArrayList<String> data = new  ArrayList<String>();
        for (Integer i=0; i<100; i++){
            data.add("Item " + i.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

}


public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Character, String, ArrayList<String>> {

     @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Character... integers) {


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {



    }

}
```

how can I implement the class DataContainer in class AsyncTask?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private AsyncTask asyncTask;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataContainer fragment;
    private TextView textView;







    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.item1:
                Toast.makeText(this,"erfolgreich",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(this," nicht erfolgreich",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        return false;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is not the answer you are looking for. But the AsyncTask api is deprecated from Android 11. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/android-asynctask-api-deprecating-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives) link for more info