# How do I get return values from execute functions in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In android, is it possible to get return values from functions that are run in execute?

**Calling file**

```
Connector connector  = new Connector();
connector.execute("login", ipPop.getText().toString(), username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
```

**Function file**

```
public class Connector extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AsyncTask in Android. When your class extends it, you can override 3 more methods. Here you can override `onPostExecute` which is passed with data from doInBackground return. Since onPostExecute runs on UI thread you can update UI from there like cancelling progressbar.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   // "result" is data return from doInBackground method
   // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
       
}
```

[Refer this sample for your understanding](https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial)

As per latest android version, AsyncTask is deprecated avoid using it. [Check alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/android-asynctask-api-deprecating-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives)

Comment: @303 So, I understand from what you're saying is that using the alternatives should be better, but because I'm short on time, I think I should focus on using AsyncTask first then switching to the alternatives later on during the maintenance period of the project.
May I ask, does it means that I can return the values back to the function that called `execute` using `onPostExecute`?

Comment: ok. No through AsyncTask directly you can't. What you want achieve? you must be trying to login, rght? Once you start AsyncTask based on success or failure, handle UI changes in `onPostExecute` method. If you are using AsyncTask to make API call, I will suggest using library like `Retrofit`. it will be much simpler.

Comment: Oh... I see, I think I get it, thanks for your help