# Modify an AsyncTask method using a not deprecated module

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have this method that is using the deprecated module AsyncTask:

```java
private void createNewNote() {
        AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Uri> task = new AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Uri>() {
            @Override
            protected Uri doInBackground(ContentValues... params) {
               ContentValues insertValues = params[0];
               Uri rowUri = getContentResolver().insert(Notes.CONTENT_URI, insertValues);
               return rowUri;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Uri uri) {
                mNoteUri = uri;
            }
        };

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Notes.COLUMN_COURSE_ID, "");
        values.put(Notes.COLUMN_NOTE_TITLE, "");
        values.put(Notes.COLUMN_NOTE_TEXT, "");

        task.execute(values);
    }
```

I would like to use a modern module instead of AsyncTask. I tried using

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

but the thing is I need to return a value from the Background task to the Main thread, and I didn't manage to do it with newSingleThreadExecutor. Do you have any solutions? (**I want to keep things as close as possible to the actual solution**).

Comment: Is this for android? Then maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/android-asynctask-api-deprecating-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives ... otherwise, look at concepts such as futures (https://www.baeldung.com/java-future)

Comment: Yes I checked this question actually. But the difference here is that I pass a value between doInBackground and onPostExecute

Comment: You still didnt say if you are asking for Android specifically.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am, I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can using `Coroutines` and `suspend` function with Kotlin.

```
suspend fun fetchData(): YourResponse {
     // make network call
     // return your response
}
```

then you can using in activity or fragment like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val data = fetchData() // fetch on IO thread
        showData(data) // back on UI thread
    }
    
}
```

`Dispatchers.Main` handle in UI thread.
If you familiar with MVVM you can using ViewModel, you can use `viewmodelscope.launch` and listen data change with `LiveData`

For more information: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines