# Android Studio JSOUP Best practice

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, rx-java, jsoup, java-threads

I write app on Java. In my app I have many AsyncTasks with JSOUP inside. But AsyncTask is deprecated, so I found a lot of variants for change:

- Volley
- RxJava
- Threads
- Executers
- Coroutines

I want to ask what is the best choice for JSOUP instead of AsyncTask?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android AsyncTask API deprecating in Android 11.What are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/android-asynctask-api-deprecating-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives)