# Default constructor in android.os.AsyncTask is deprecated

Tags: java, android, constructor

I have some troubles with this warning in Android Studio in one of my java classes.
Default constructor in android.os.AsyncTask is deprecated.. I use latest target SDK.

```
public CleanFilesTask(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Consumer < Integer > callback) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(context);
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        mCallback = Objects.requireNonNull(callback);
    }
```

How to solve this warning and make it not showing deprecated? XD

Link for full class: https://github.com/D4rK7355608/com.d4rk.cleaner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/d4rk/cleaner/invalid/task/CleanFilesTask.java

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: Thanks XD I want it to make it not showing that "deprecated" without disable inspection in settings. I tried to search on Android Developers and didn't find any solution XD

Comment: From the [`AsyncTask` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask): "*This class was deprecated in API level 30. Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.*"

Comment: Ahh, didn't noticed this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [google doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

> This class was deprecated in API level 30.
> Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

you can check concurrent tutorial on [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines),

and how to migrate from AsyncTask to concurrent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58767934/5317552)