# Android Asyntask API deprecated

Tags: android

Been looking on the internet how to check the current app version of the application and the version available on Play Store. But it was using `Asynctask` that was deprecated already and I`ve been looking alternative way aside from` Asynctask `been searching on the internet but I couldn`t figure out how to do it correctly. Please check the code below:

```
private class GetLatestVersion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String latestVersion;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean manualCheck;
    GetLatestVersion(boolean manualCheck) {
        this.manualCheck = manualCheck;
    }
    
        String currentVersion = getCurrentVersion();
        //If the versions are not the same
        if(!currentVersion.equals(latestVersion)&&latestVersion!=null){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_warning_dialog);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Button tryAgain = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_positive);
            Button settings = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_negative);
            tryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+activity.getPackageName())));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    activity.finish();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }else {
            if (manualCheck) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "No Update Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //It retrieves the latest version by scraping the content of current version from play store at runtime
            latestVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activity.getPackageName() + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
                    .get(7)
                    .ownText();
            return latestVersion;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return latestVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android AsyncTask API deprecating in Android 11.What are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/android-asynctask-api-deprecating-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives)

Comment: Downvoted, because of constant "android" questions being tagged as "android-studio" ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler I was able to figure it out I use Executer it is the easiest way for me as beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can basically convert `asyncTask` to coroutine on kotlin

```
private suspend fun GetLatestVersion(String,String,String) {

   withContext(Dispatcher.Default)
   {
        // you just have to refactor all your code inside doInBaakground inside this withContext
   }

   //then if you want to update the UI
   withContext(Dispatchers.Main) 
   {
      //return code for your task
   }
}
```

See this [link](https://heartbeat.comet.ml/replacing-asynctask-in-android-with-kotlin-coroutines-to-handle-background-tasks-93108f8f2db) . For further information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ginxx, but I used executer instead of coroutine since I am only a beginner but it might help others who the same as me.

Check my update codes below:

```
public void CheckLatestAppVersionFromPlayStore() {
    final String[] latestAppVersionFromPlayStore = new String[1];
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //It retrieves the latest version by scraping the content of current version from play store at runtime
                latestAppVersionFromPlayStore[0] = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activityWeakReference.get().getPackageName() + "&hl=it")
                        .timeout(30000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .get()
                        .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
                        .get(7)
                        .ownText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String installedAppVersion = currentVersionName;
                    //If the versions are not the same
                    if (!installedAppVersion.equals(latestAppVersionFromPlayStore[0]))
                        if (latestAppVersionFromPlayStore[0] != null) {
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activityWeakReference.get());
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_warning_dialog);
                            dialog.setCancelable(false);
                            Button tryAgain = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_positive);
                            Button settings = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_negative);
                            tryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    activityWeakReference.get().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activityWeakReference.get().getPackageName())));
                                }
                            });
                            settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    activityWeakReference.get().finish();
                                }
                            });
                            // to avoid the bad token exception
                            if ((activityWeakReference.get() != null) && (!activityWeakReference.get().isFinishing()) && (!activityWeakReference.get().isDestroyed()))
                                dialog.show();
                        }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

For further information please click this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__ObR-DSBlE).