# Does Kotlin Coroutines replace AsyncTask?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines

Is `AsyncTask` still needed?

In Android with Java, we used to implement an `AsyncTask` and `AsyncTaskLoader`, but recently I've been beginning to learn Kotlin and I've noticed that things like that are done by Kotlin Coroutines.

Comment: Deprecated code shouldn't be used; it is declared as deprecated by documentation after offering some existing or new alternatives. You just need it to understand or refactor some old code.

Comment: Please see this post on how to use Kotlin Coroutines instead of `AsyncTask` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62748880/1731626

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has been officially deprecated since Android 11.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Coroutines are the recommended choice, and considering Kotlin is the official language since 2017, then using `AsyncTask` is no longer a standard option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use Kotlin Coroutines to perform async operations now.

If you are looking for Coroutine usage, then here is an example of using Coroutines to fetch data from different sources asynchronously:-

https://codingnconcepts.com/kotlin/fetch-data-from-sources-async/