# Updating UI asynchronously isn't working for native android application

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a list view in the home screen widget of my android app which fetches items from a database and then updates values in the listview. Since AsyncTask is deprecated, [I have tried to use handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/the-asynctask-api-is-deprecated-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives/64969640#64969640). The add item method outside the execute method is working, but the code inside post method(which is dependent on the fetched data) isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

```kt
val todosRemoteView = RemoteViews.RemoteCollectionItems.Builder()
val handler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

backgroundExecutor.execute {
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        AppDatabase::class.java, "db"
    ).build()
    val todosDAO = db.TodoDAO()
    val todos: List<Todo> = todosDAO.getByTimeType(timeTypeHash[timeType]!!)
    
    handler.post {
        Log.d("debugging", "all the todos for ${timeTypeHash[timeType]} are $todos")
        for (todo in todos) {
            val view = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.each_todo).apply {
                setTextViewText(R.id.each_todo_container_text, todo.taskName)
                setCompoundButtonChecked(
                    R.id.each_todo_container_checkbox,
                    todo.finished!!
                )
            }
            todosRemoteView.addItem(
                todo.id.toString().toInt().toLong(),
                                    view
            )//this doesn't works
        }
        Log.d("debugging", "update is triggered");
    }
}

todosRemoteView.addItem(//this works
849938,
RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.each_todo).apply {
    setTextViewText(R.id.each_todo_container_text, "random")
    setCompoundButtonChecked(
        R.id.each_todo_container_checkbox,
        false
    )
})
setRemoteAdapter(
    R.id.todos_list,
    todosRemoteView
    .build()
)
```

Comment: Does the `post` method of handler get executed? Did you see its logs?

Comment: yes, the post method's logs are visible

Comment: Can you enhance your codes in the question so that it can be used as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Kozmotronik please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74740967/cant-update-ui-asynchronously-with-co-routines

Comment: I did it @Pro, but still not much difference, still a reproducible example needed. For instance, what do you execute in `RemoteView.addItem` function? This kind of implementation doesn't seem to match the guidelines like MVVM.

Comment: In your implementation it looks like you instantiate a new item view everytime a `TODO` record is obtained from the database. But you must used an already instantiated one by a recycler view perhaps or whatever framework you use to list the `TODO` items. So instantiating items is your own buissness but instantiating views for items is not yours. It is the buissness of the underlaying framework to do so. I hope it is clear enough to understand.