# Can't update UI asynchronously with co routines

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, android-view, kotlin-coroutines

I am calling a suspend function in my android home screen widget(AppWidgetProvider class) using async-await syntax inside co-routine scope. The values are fetched from the database and they are logged properly. But the UI isn't updated with the same values. This is the code pertaining to the co-routine:

```
            scope.launch {
                val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "db"
                ).build()
                val todosDAO = db.TodoDAO()
                val todosAsync = async {
                    todosDAO.getByTimeType("day")
                }
                val todos = todosAsync.await()

                Log.d("debugging", "all the todos for day are $todos")//values get logged
                for (todo in todos) {
                    val view = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.each_todo).apply {
                        setTextViewText(
                            R.id.each_todo_container_text,
                            todo.taskName
                        )//the view text value isn't updated here
                        Log.d("debugging", "task name is ${todo.taskName}")//this gets printed
                    }
                    todosRemoteView.addItem(todo.id.toString().toInt().toLong(), view)
                }
            }
```

Comment: You cannot change UI elements from a non-UI thread.

Comment: So how am i supposed to do it then?

Comment: By looking at your code I assume you are trying to fetch some results from your database and then display them in your fragment / activity, is that correct?

Comment: yeah you are right, but its not just an activity, its the AppWidgetProvider

Comment: I haven't really worked with those yet, but normally what you would do is create a viewModel, which fetches the data from your database in a coroutine and then (either using Rx or LiveData) passes it to your fragment / activity (which you can learn more about here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0)

Also: You should NOT create a database instance like that, this will create a new database on every app run, which makes your app bigger and your data... stored in a strange, inaccessible way

Comment: Cool, I will look into the codelabs example. About the 2nd point, if I create a single instance of my database in my main activity then how can I access that in other classes?

Comment: Normally, you would use dagger or hilt to create and inject your database instance (and repositories) into fragments / activities, but that's a bit complicated if you haven't got much experience, so what I would recommend is creating something like the WordRoomDatabase here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#7 (Tbh all of the info about working with databases in android is pretty much covered in the codelab)

Comment: oh cool. I will go through the codelab. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No worries, later I will drop of some example code if nobody does that before me (maybe even you)

Comment: yes you can do that, Getting your date in the back-thread then using the result in main thread using coroutines

Comment: @providerZ "then using the result in main thread using coroutines", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @JustSightseeing use lifecycle scope coroutines  then call onThread UI scope then do what ever you want in main thread

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to update the UI elements from a non-UI thread.

Here is an example on how we update the UI inside a coroutine

```
    fun someFunction() {
    // Execute the code in worker thread
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        // Get data
        val dataAsync = async { getData() }
        val data = dataAsync.await()

        // Then use `withContext` with `Dispatchers.Main` to update the UI
        // Just like as it said in `Dispatchers.Main` description:
        // Dispatchers.Main -> "A coroutine dispatcher that is confined to the Main thread operating with UI objects"
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            mainTextView!!.text = data.toString()
        }
    }
}
```