# Put url image in ImageView Using Executors instead of The AsyncTask not working, app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Due to the deprecate of AsyncTask API according to this [question (Accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/the-asynctask-api-is-deprecated-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives) I try to change my codes but I don't know what is the problem , app will be crash when  : `Bitmap tmpBitmap = mImageLoadTask.call();` invokes.

Please help me, I spent a lot of time, but I don't understand where the problem is.

My codes:

**class ImageLoadTask:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
public class ImageLoadTask implements Callable<Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private Context mContex;
    public ImageLoadTask(String url, Context contex) {
        this.url = url;
        this.mContex = contex;
    }
    @Override
    public Bitmap call() {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }catch (IOException exception){
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContex.getResources(), R.drawable.ee);
        }

    }
}
```

**class TaskRunner:**

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TaskRunner {
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // change according to your requirements
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public interface Callback<R> {
        void onComplete(R result);
    }

    public <R> void executeAsync(Callable<R> callable, Callback<R> callback) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            final R result;
            try {
                result = callable.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            handler.post(() -> {
                callback.onComplete(result);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**in Activity:**

```
public class Sendtoserver extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Context mContext;
    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
    ImageView mImgfromurl;
    Button getfromurlbtn;


    ImageLoadTask mImageLoadTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sendtoserver);

        mImgfromurl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgfromurl_id);
        getfromurlbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getfromurl_btn_id);

        mImageLoadTask = new ImageLoadTask("https://www.ourartag.com/upload/pic.jpg", getContext() );
        getfromurlbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Bitmap tmpBitmap = mImageLoadTask.call();
                    mImgfromurl.setImageBitmap(tmpBitmap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

error Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.ourartag.eandroid, PID: 24006
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                                        at com.ourartag.eandroid.Sendtoserver$2.onClick(Sendtoserver.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
                                                                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:426)
                                                                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.writeInternal(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:657)
                                                                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.access$200(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:616)
                                                                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.drainOutgoingQueue(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:585)
                                                                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.close(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:480)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:95)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.deallocate(StreamAllocation.java:295)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.connectionFailed(StreamAllocation.java:332)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.close(HttpEngine.java:591)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:513)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
```

It didn't matter if this line was there or not.

in activity onClick :

```
mImgfromurl.setImageBitmap(tmpBitmap);
```

Comment: Your problem is you're not using asynchronous programming correctly at all.  You image task isn't being used asynchrnously, and you don't seem to understand threading.  With your level of knowledge, I suggest using Picasso, Glide, or another image processing library to download the image and load it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your guid. I think I found the answer but still trying to do this myself not using that . I think I have to use : taskRunner.executeAsync(new ImageLoadTask(url) -> {}

Comment: In addition, my App used to work perfectly with  AsyncTask API. but it is deprecated